# ZPL language - cannot rotate label

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, thermal-printer, zpl, zpl-ii

Hi I'm working with a Zebra printer GC420t.
I'm trying to print the same label two times:

- the first time with vertical orientation.
- the second time with horizontal orientation.

If I try to draw that labels on the "Labelary Online Zpl" (http://labelary.com/viewer.html) it seems to work well.
If I try to print the labels the vertical it print all the fields on the same line.

Some advices?

```
**Vertical** 

^XA
^CFA,40
^FO50,100^FDTest1^FS
^FO50,250^FD100.00^FS
^FO50,400^BY2,0,80^BC^FD101.00^FS
^FO50,550^FDTest2^FS"
^XZ
```

```
**Horizontal**

^XA

^FWB

^CFA,40
^FO100,50^FDTest1^FS
^FO250,50^FD100.00^FS
^FO400,50^BY2,0,80^BC^FD101.00^FS
^FO550,50^FDTest2^FS"
^XZ
```

Comment: Try downloading the latest driver : https://www.barcodesinc.com/zebra/gc420t-drivers.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a sketchy solution, but try using the ^A command:

```
^XA
^CF,40
^FO100,50^AAB^FDTest1^FS
^FO250,50^AAB^FD100.00^FS
^FO400,50^AAB^BY2,0,80^BC^FD101.00^FS
^FO550,50^AAB^FDTest2^FS"
^XZ
```

Why it is sketchy? You have to set the font and the rotation for every ^FD.

*Edit, in my first answer I used font A in CF command and that is not neccessary.